# Should we burninate the tags [repeat] and [repeating]?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, tags

The tags [repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repeat) and [repeating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repeating) ([repeated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repeated) was burninated earlier), are mostly used when *something* is repeated or *something* is repeating. No tag wiki, they are used with different tags (languages). Sometimes they are used when [XML nodes are repeated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095912/delete-xml-repeated-tags) or [data is repeated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135294/repeated-data-in-my-spinner-and-listview) or [background image is repeated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534498/reflected-repeated-background-image-with-css-or-js).

Should these tags be burninated? So that no one *repeat* the mistake to tag them.

Comment: It does seem a superfluous and unnecessary tag - I agree, burn, pulverise and nuke that tag.

Comment: @UV-D: Well, in theory, nuking does already burn and pulverize it. ;)

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby true, but there is something to be said with being thorough

Comment: [repeat] too while we're at it?

Comment: @Wooble - Yeah it seems unwanted too. Updated. Thanks.

Comment: Fortunately, Search says that this request is not a repeat. *(I'm sorry. I just had to.)*

Comment: @michaelb958 - I *repeated* that process twice before requesting. :)

Comment: @Wooble - [repeating] also needs to be removed.

Answer (score 7):

The 116 questions with the [repeated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repeated) tag have been repeatedly zapped — there were no questions left with the tag just now, so it will vanish soon.  Two of the questions had a [repeating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repeating) tag too, but I've not tackled the other two tags; there are quite a lot more entries for them.

Answer (score 6):

I shall call once again *(and repeat my self from other posts...)* :

## Troggy My dear friend

[image: TROGGY]

I feel like these tags are only meta data from the question. I mean who really cares that, for example, the same image is repeated. It's still a CSS or w/e technology used in the problem and it's not really a problem because it's repeated.

Reading more questions, people are talking about applying multiple of the same thing (example a Java filter)... who care if you apply more than one filter... the problem is about filter not multiple filter, since applying repeatedly filters is the same as applying one filter, and then "forwarding" that request to a new service that would apply only one filter (and that new service sees the request as if it had never had a filter applied).

Comment: Your argument is wrong (sometimes it is significant that something is repeated), but your conclusion is correct (burninate it).