# Questions with [repeat] are repeatedly tagged with [repeating]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I asked a question [How to gather support for tag synonyms?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312430/how-to-gather-support-for-tag-synonyms). The answer was to ask on meta to popularize the request.

[repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repeat) -  1071 Questions

> "repeat" refers to the action of doing something over again.

[repeating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repeating) - 314 Questions (Pi, Pi everywhere)

> The repeating tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

I propose to make [repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repeat) a synonym of [repeating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repeating).

Comment: Can you provide more specific usage guidance for repeat?  It sounds like one of those tags that exists only because people type their question titles in the tag box.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom There is not much usage. There was a burninate request also (but it did not gather support)

Comment: [Should we burninate the tags \[repeated\], \[repeat\] and \[repeating\]?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255432/should-we-burninate-the-tags-repeated-repeat-and-repeating)